# When 3 sets of 2 points each on different sides of a triangle are pairwise cyclic, are they all on the same circle?

Tags: geometry

When 3 sets of 2 points each on different sides of a triangle are pairwise cyclic, are they all on the same circle?
So suppose $a_1, a_2$ are on $[BC]$, $b_1,b_2$ are on $[AC]$, $c_1,c_2$ are on $[AB]$, and $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ are cyclic, etc. are they all on the same circle?

Answer (score 0):

For a counterexample, take $ABC$ to be an equilateral triangle, and then take

- $a_1 =$ the midpoint of $[BC]$,
- $b_1 = $ the midpoint of $[CA]$,
- $c_1 = $ the midpoint of $[AB]$

and so $a_1,b_1,c_1$ lie on the inscribed circle. Next, choose a very small number $\epsilon>0$, much smaller than the side length of $ABC$, and choose

- $a_2 =$ the point on $[BC]$ at distance $\epsilon$ from $C$
- $b_2 =$ the point on $[CA]$ at distance $\epsilon$ from $A$
- $c_2 =$ the point on $[AB]$ at distance $\epsilon$ from $B$

and so $a_2,b_2,c_2$ lie on a circle very close to the circumscribed circle.

Thus, the circle through $a_1,b_1,c_1$ and the circle through $a_2,b_2,c_2$ are different from each other.